How to improve the gradient algorithm?
I've recently become interested in the gradient algorithm.
After a first implementation in Node.js, I obtained satisfactory results.
Sometimes, the algorithm diverges. For example, with the Rosenbrock function, it doesn't work with α = 0.01, but it does with α = 0.001.
Question: For the moment I'm using constant α, but do you know of an effective strategy for adjusting α automatically?
Secondly, I thought that the gradient search wasn't always efficient and that we might get better results with a dichotomous search.
eg: in dimension 1, if we take f(x) = (x - 3)^2 + 1 and look for the minimum on [0; 10].

The algorithm consists in subdividing the interval into 4: { 0; 3.33; 6.67; 10 }.
The images are calculated: { 10; 1.11; 33.11; 50 }.
Exclude the maximum. Finally, we reduce our search to [0; 6.67].
By recursion, we converge to x = 3 (f(3) = 1).

This algorithm only works if the function has a unique minimum .
Unfortunately, I've come across a case where this algorithm doesn't provide the optimal solution in dimension 2.
Question: Do you know of any algorithms that are more efficient than the gradient algorithm? Or how to improve it? I'm a novice in these fields but the subject interests me.
Thanks in advance :-)
